# Dudas con punteros y Listas enlazadas en C

Tags: c, lista, punteros

Tengo que hacer una lista que contenga la id y notas de la cantidad de alumnos introducidos por teclado (`num_max_alumnos`), el caso es que al imprimirlo no me aparece nada por pantalla, debería aparecer la ID y Notas que estoy dándoles en el apartado de `INSERTAMOS LOS DATOS EN LA LISTA`

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

    typedef struct alumno
    {
        int id;
        float nota;
        struct alumno *next; //El puntero siguiente para recorrer la lista 
    }alumno;
    
int main(){
    
    alumno *inicio=NULL,*nuevo=NULL,*fin=NULL;
    
    int i=0;
    
    int num_max_alumnos=0;
    
    printf("Digite el numero de alumnos a analizar: ");
    scanf("&d",num_max_alumnos);
    
    //INSERTAMOS LOS DATOS EN LA LISTA
    
    for(i=0;i<=num_max_alumnos;i++){
        nuevo = (alumno*)malloc(sizeof(alumno)); //malloc para reservarle memoria al nodo
        nuevo->id = i+1; //La id será su posición en la lista
        nuevo->nota = ((nuevo->id * 10)%12); //La nota del alumno será el resto de dividir 12 por multiplicar por 10 el identificador
        nuevo->next = NULL;
        
        if(nuevo!=NULL){
            if(i==0){
                nuevo->next=inicio;
                inicio=nuevo;
            }
        }else{
            if(nuevo!=NULL){
                while(fin->next!=NULL){
                    fin=fin->next;
                    fin=nuevo;  
                }
                fin->next=nuevo;
            }   
        }
        fin=nuevo;
    }
    
    //IMPRIMIMOS LOS DATOS DE LA LISTA
        
    while(fin!=NULL){
        printf("ID= %d\n",fin->id);
        printf("Nota= %f\n",fin->nota);
        fin=fin->next;
    }

return 0;
}
```

EDIT 2: SOLUCIONADO

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

    typedef struct alumno
    {
        int id;
        float nota;
        struct alumno *next; //El puntero siguiente para recorrer la lista 
    }alumno;
    
int main(){
    
    alumno *inicio=NULL,*nuevo=NULL,*fin=inicio;
    
    int i=0;
    
    int num_max_alumnos=0;
    
    printf("Digite el numero de alumnos a analizar: ");
    scanf("%d", &num_max_alumnos);
    
    //INSERTAMOS LOS DATOS EN LA LISTA
    
    for(i=0;i<num_max_alumnos;i++){
        nuevo = (alumno*)malloc(sizeof(alumno)); //malloc para reservarle memoria al nodo
        nuevo->id = i+1; //La id será su posición en la lista
        nuevo->nota = ((nuevo->id * 10)%12); //La nota del alumno será el resto de dividir 12 por multiplicar por 10 el identificador
        nuevo->next = NULL;
        
        if(nuevo!=NULL){
            nuevo->next=inicio;
            inicio=nuevo;
        }else{
            while(fin->next!=NULL){
                fin=fin->next;
            }
            fin->next=nuevo;
        }
        fin=nuevo;
    }
    
    //IMPRIMIMOS LOS DATOS DE LA LISTA
        
    while(fin!=NULL){
        printf("ID= %d\n",fin->id);
        printf("Nota= %f\n",fin->nota);
        fin=fin->next;
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Así de primeras, el scanf le falta el & en la variable num_max_alumnos

Comment: En el bucle de impresión siempre imprimes los datos del elemento fin. Aquí la cosa es imprimir los datos del puntero `inicio`, y luego ir avanzando, asignando el ->Next. No debes usar un bucle for en este caso, porque tu condición debería ser que ->Next no sea nulo. Revisa como tienes creada la lista.